# What is the X that appears on the top right corner when multiple tabs are open?

Tags: tabbed-user-interface

What is that X on the corner? What is it for and what does it do?

I opened Vim with `vim -p tab1 tab2` on Windows 10 and in WLS with Ubuntu and they both have it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allows you to close a tab with a mouse. (You'll probably need to enable mouse support enabled)

Comment: I just tested mouse support using `:set mouse=a` and the `x` does not seem to close any tabs but it disables the mouse instead.

Comment: Hmm odd, try opening vim without custom settings with `vim -u NONE` and try again to rule out a plugin or setting. Check out `:help tabline' etc reading help for vim v 7.1 (have that to hand only) it suggests that the X isn't supported on all systems/terminal emulators...

Comment: The mouse did not work on Windows 10 with Vim 8.1. On Ubuntu Vim 8.0 I can use the mouse but even when using `vim -u NONE` the X still only disables the mouse option. I tried the `:help tabline` command on both versions and it mentions using an `%X` option to close labels but not clicking on the X on the corner to close tabs.